# PHP Caching Question

Tags: php

I recently worked on a project on .NET and part of the code involved reading the header and footer from a pre-defined format for consistency across various websites shared by the same client.

I am faced by a similar problem in php. I get the contents of the header/footer links using:

```
<?php
$contents = file_get_contents('http://www.mysite.com/common/footer.asp');
echo $contents;
?>
```

Is there a way I can load this into cache to avoid repeated calls to http://www.mysite.com/common/footer.asp

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your looking to cache across many page loads, you could use the session.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['somekey'] = value;
```

Or into persistent storage like a [flat file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), [database](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcache.php).

Answer (score 3):

You can use APC's caching if you have the extension available:

```
$contents = apc_fetch('footer');
if (!$contents) {
    $contents = file_get_contents('http://www.mysite.com/common/footer.asp');
    apc_store('footer', $contents);
}
```

If you want to use the same cache across different machines or don't have APC available then  memcached could be used in a very similar fashion.

Comment: I do this for reducing i/o for reading/writing XML files. This is a very good solution.

Comment: I am using a shared host environment on dreamhost. I am not sure they have APC installed or memcache. I understand that I have to install these as well as some extensions and restart apache. That doesn't seem like something they would do.

Comment: @kenyana you can check easily with `phpinfo();`

Comment: If they're not using APC, you can always request to be moved to a box that has it. They're very accommodating over there. You have not because you ask not!